# Tkinter Scale border color

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a tkinter app for work that involves cropping images. I use sliders to allow a user to crop a specific part of an image and save that image. My problem right now is that my sliders have a white border that isn't matching up with the background of the window.

**My App Currently:**

[image]

So what i'm trying to do is get rid of these borders.

**My Code**

```
self.left = Scale(main, label='left', orient='h',
                          from_=0, to=400, length=400, command=self.onSliderLeft, bg='#2E4970', fg='white', bd=0, troughcolor='grey')
self.left.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)

self.right = Scale(main, label='right', orient='h',
                           from_=0, to=400, length=400, command=self.onSliderRight, bg='#2E4970', fg='white', bd=0, troughcolor='grey')
self.right.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)

self.top = Scale(main, label='top', orient='v',
                         from_=0, to=400, length=400, command=self.onSliderTop, bg='#2E4970', fg='white', bd=0, troughcolor='grey')
self.top.grid(row=4, column=2, rowspan=4)

self.bottom = Scale(main, label='bottom', orient='v',
                            from_=0, to=400, length=400, command=self.onSliderBottom, bg='#2E4970', fg='white', bd=0, troughcolor='grey')
self.bottom.grid(row=4, column=3, rowspan=4)
```

*Comment:*
I know that tkinter's Scale() has a bd (border) attribute, but even at 0 it still shows up.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I don't see this on my system, but I suspect this is a result of the `highlightthickness` and/or `highlightbackground` attributes. Are you aware of those attributes, and have you checked their values?

Comment: it might be some gap caused by the grid layout manager on your system. try wrapping the scales in an extra "Frame" widget and display tehn with ".pack" rather than ".grid".

Comment: Those borders are removed by setting `highlightthickness=0` in my Windows 10 running Python 3.10.2.